# Links and Z-Index

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with a scroll effect where I cant get the links to work within the header because the `z-index` has to be negative for the effect to work. The links are in the header.

**EDIT** Sorry I wasnt clear enough, the links in the header area (green) are not active because of the z-index properties giving the header area a negative index it makes the links not active so I was wondering a fix for it

http://jsfiddle.net/ThAv5/4/

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="navBar"></div> 
    <div id="headerBar"></div>
    <div id="mainContent"><h1>This is the main content</h1></div>
</div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
#navBar{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
    background:red;
    height:50px;
}

#headerBar{
    top: 0;
    height: 250px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:-1000;
    background:green;
}

#mainContent{
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top: 250px;
    width:100%;
    height:900px;
}

body, #container{
    background:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there are no links in the code you've provided, I'm assuming that the links are in the "headerBar" div. If that's the case, you're not able to click them because they will appear under the "navBar" div because of the styles you've provided.

If this is the effect you want, then specify a margin or padding for the "headerBar" div, that will allow you to push the links below the "navBar".

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear enough, the links in the header area not the top nav area are not active because of the z-index properties giving the header area a negative index it makes the links not active so I was wondering a fix for it

Answer (score 1):

Actually #navBar overlaps #headerBar and so #headerBar content is not visible. It should be below #navBar whose height is 50px. So set top offset of #headerBar to 50px

```
#headerBar {
top:50px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThAv5/7/)